# Finding numbers when their sum and LCM are given

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> The sum of two numbers is $2000$ and thier LCM is $21879.$ Find the numbers.

My attempt: Let two numbers be $x, 2000-x.$ Product of two numbers is equal to the product of their lcm and hcf. So, $x(2000-x)=21879*hcf.$

Now we have two variables and one equation. So I am stuck.

But the book simply considers $x(2000-x)=21879,$ thereby $x=1989,11.$

My question is - Is it implied anywhere in the question that hcf is $1$ or is the question incomplete?

More impotantly, can we have any other pair of numbers whose sum is $2000$ and lcm is $21879 (hcf <> 1)?$

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080702042039AAbPfBX

Comment: I am feeling a little embarassed because even after reading the detailed answer on that site, I am not confident enough to answer similar questions. I don't know what's wrong with my understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $21879$ and $2000$ are coprime. So this means that $x$ and $2000-x$ are coprime (simply because their gcd must divide $x+(2000-x)=2000$).

Comment: I wish I could have a detailed answer. I am still not able to see clearly and confidently.

Comment: Let $d={\text{gcd}}(x,2000-x)$, we saw that $d|2000$, but also, since $x$ divides ${\text{lcm}}(x,2000-x) = 21879$, we have that $d | 21879$ too. But $21879$ and $2000$ are coprime, hence $d = 1$ since $d$ divides both of them.

Now remember that we have ${\text{lcm}}(a,b) = \frac{a \cdot b}{{\text{gcd}}(a,b)}$.

Comment: oh, that's beautiful! really thanks! So gcd is not just common factor for a and b. it's also common factor for a*b and a+b. Now that I am writing it, it's appearing too obvious to me. I am sure I won't stuck on such thing in future now. thanks.